# The boundary of a domain without a closed subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $D$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$  ($N\geq2$) and $E$ a closed subset of $D$ with empty interior. Show that the boundary of $D\setminus E$ is the union of $E$ and the boundary of $D$:
$$\partial(D\setminus E)=\partial D\cup E.$$

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I found one. Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A:=D\setminus E$. Then
\begin{align*}
\partial A&=\overline{A}\setminus A\\
&=\overline{D}\setminus (D\setminus E)\\
&=\overline{D}\cap D^{\complement}\cup (\overline{D}\cap E)\\
&=\partial D\cup S,
\end{align*}
where the bar over the set indicates its closure and the top "C" is for the complement.